# How to Teleport Players When They Enter a Certain Area/Coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to teleport a player to certain coordinates once they enter an area.

The idea is that they walk into a really small building, but once they turn a corner, they get teleported into a larger building.

Please refer to the adventure map named '5 Cubed', if you need help understanding what I am asking.

Comment: I think you can just put `\tp **** **** ****` The asterisk being the x, y, and z coordinates. I'm not 100% positive about that though. Also a pressure plate on a block and a command block under that.

Comment: @zombieatmore This only works in single player. It will only `tp` the player who uses it. So it is useless for use with command blocks.

Comment: @AngusAtkinson I wasn't 100% sure if mine was correct either way so.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1.9 Solution

Place the following command in a repeating command block set to always active:

```
/execute @a[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=d] ~ ~ ~ tp @p e f g
```

Where:

- `a`, `b`, and `c` are the XYZ co-ordinates that you want to teleport players *from*
- `d` is the radius in blocks around that point where players will be selected (min 1)
- `e`, `f`, and `g` are the XYZ co-ordinates that you want to teleport players *to* (i.e. the destination)

---

## 1.8 Solution

Use the same command as above, but since no repeating command blocks exist, place the command block on a [fill clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227011/how-do-i-make-a-setblock-or-a-fill-clock).

Comment: Is there a possible way to replace radius with something like, "~ ~ ~"? I'm also looking for a way to test for a player at certain co-ordinates. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, however not by the `/tp` command. Use a `/testfor` command

Comment: @Jake Try `/testfor @a[x=? y=? z=?]`, with a comparator pointing out of the command block. This will produce a current when a player is at the certain co-ords.

Answer (score 0):

**1.13.x solution**

If anyone is coming from 1.13.x, the /testfor command has been deleted.
In that case if you want to teleport someone you can use the /execute command as thus

```
/execute if entity @a[x=0,y=0,z=0,distance=..1] run tp @p x y z
```

The first set of X Y Z coordinates is where you want the player to be teleported from, the second is where you want the player to be teleported to.

Answer (score -1):

Put pressure plates around your desired area. under each pressure plate place a command block that will teleport you to coordinates of your choice. do this by inserting the command `/tp @p x y z` into your command block.

Answer (score -2):

It's actually quite easy:

Just have a command block that is on a clock, and it should constantly testfor a player at certain co-ords:

```
/testfor @a[x=???,y=???,z=???]
```

(copy exactly except replace ? with the co-ords) then put a comparater leading out of it to a command block that:

```
/tp @p ??? ??? ??? (x,y,z).
```

You can also do:

```
/test for @a[x=???,y=???,z=???,r=?]
```

Where r is a radius (i.e. if r is 3 it will test for players within 3 blocks in a directions of the co-ords specified.

Comment: This does not work. This will just teleport the player closest to the command block when *any* player enters the coordinates.