# Minecraft - teleport a player when stepping on specific coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Currently I try to understand command blocks in minecraft. The next step I try to achieve is to teleport a player, when he steps on a block at specific coordinates. I found many solutions about that, but the solution is always for a case that a player steps on a block (e.g. stone). But I try to execute the command only when the player steps on one specific block. I found [this thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/how-to-teleport-players-when-they-enter-a-certain-area-coordinates) which is exactly what I need.

But for some reason it doesn't work. I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. I try to execute a command when the player steps on the block at coordinates x=-637 y=67 z=620. So I placed a command block below this coordinates and entered the following command:

```
/execute @a[x=-637,y=67,z=620,r=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @p -640 67 625
```

But as I said before, it doesn't work. I don't want to do it with a pressure plate. The player should not see that there's something special. I'm using Minecraft version 1.10.2.

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Is the command block a repeating command block that is activated?

Comment: Yes, I set it to "Repeat" and "Always active"

Comment: Do you want the player to teleport when standing on stone?

Comment: The block doesn't matter on which the player stands. I also tried using "/execute detect" with e.g. "minecraft:grass", but then it executes everytime the player moves on grass, no matter where the player is. Thats not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What error message are you getting in the command block?

Comment: `/execute` here is unnecessary and only causes more work for the server. Use the selector for `/execute` in `/tp` instead. Is there a reason you're using 1.10, such as for mods? Keep in mind that vanilla command mechanics rarely work alongside mods.

Comment: @SirBenet There is no error message in the command block when using the command above.

Comment: @Skylinerw yes, I'm using a mod which is developed for MC 1.10.2, no later version for now.

Comment: @Roman If you put `/say test` in the command block, is `test` spammed to chat?

Comment: @SirBenet Nope, it doesn't write anything to chat.

Comment: @SirBenet Okay I guess I found the problem. If I first save the command block with "Impulse" and then change it to "Repeat" it doesn't work. If I create the command block and immediately save it as "Repeat" then it works... Oh and I also had to update y coordinate to 68. Why doesn't it work when I first save it as "Impulse" and later as "Repeat"? Is that a bug?

Comment: @Roman Repeating command blocks need to be ticked once to schedule themselves to tick again in future ticks. Setting them to repeating from an impulse or chain block will not tick them.

Comment: @SirBenet Oh, okay. Good to know. I'll remember that for the next time. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

I will test this when I get access to a desktop, but I belive `tp @a[x=?,y=?,z=?,r=1] x y z` on repeat should work. It worked for me in 1.7, but I haven't tested this on 1.10 yet.

Comment: The problem is already solved. See the comments under the question. But thx anyway.

Comment: @Roman You still need to formally mark an answer as correct; keeps it off the homepage.

Comment: @aytimothy The problem was solved in the comments by SirBenet. I haven't tested your suggestion so I cannot say if it would work and if it is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would be better to use `/tp` rather than `/execute`. They both work the same, but personally I prefer `/tp` by putting this on a Repeat, Always Active command block:

`/tp @a[x=number,y=number,z=number,r=1] x y z`

Answer (score 0):

Try `/tp @a[r=R] x y z` where:

- `R` is the radius of selection. So, for instance, if the block is two blocks under the spot you want players to teleport from, you would set R=3. Note that this is *radius*, which means that players in *any* direction within three blocks will be teleported. Therefore, place the command block as close to the target spot as possible and block off any other spots players might get teleported from, so as to prevent them from getting teleported as well.
- `(x,y,z)` is the target destination.

Plug this into a command block on repeat and always active, and you're golden.

Answer (score -1):

Try the command:

`/execute @a -637 67 620 tp @a[r=1,c=1] -640 67 625`

This will teleport everybody in a radius of 1 block from the coordinates `-637 67 620` to the coordinates `-640 67 625`.

Comment: The `/execute` command is causing all online players to run a command to target all players in a particular location. This causes unnecessary processing of commands and selectors; the first player that runs `/tp` will have removed those players from the area, and then all other players are still going to be running a `/tp` command, except they will all fail while still having to process the selector anew just to find no players. You should only be using `/execute` if the origin or sender needs to be changed, which is not needed here.

Answer (score -2):

```
/execute @a -637 67 620 tp @p -640 67 625
```