# How do you teleport players at specific coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I saw [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/how-to-teleport-players-when-they-enter-a-certain-area-coordinates) question asking for the same thing and tried it on PE, but it didn't work. I put `execute @a[x=11, y=4, z=0, r=1] ~ ~ ~ tp @p 11 4 -2` in a repeating command block, but it ignored the `x=11`, `y=4`, `z=0` and `r=1` and constantly kept teleporting me even though I was not on `x=11, y=4, z=0`. If it is possible, how would you teleport players that are on specific coordinates?

I am on single player and on version 1.1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x`, `y` and `z` arguments in the target selector only move the origin of where to search for players, you still need a radius (`r`) or range (`dx`, `dy`, `dz`).

Also you don't need execute in this example, you can just put the target selector in the `tp' command.

So your command could for example look like this:

```
tp @a[x=11,y=4,z=0,r=1] 11 4 -2
```

A tip for dealing with repeating command blocks with teleport commands in them: In case anything goes wrong and you're stuck in a teleporting loop, write down the coordinates of the repeating command block beforehand and if it's out of control, execute the command `/blockdata <coordinates> {auto:0}` to stop it.

Comment: I forgot to add I did use `r=1` in my command. `/blockdata` is not available in PE, but I could use `/setblock X Y Z air` to get rid of the command block.