# Minecraft 1.16.5 - Teleport a player to a given location if on given coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

> I already tried [this link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/how-to-teleport-players-when-they-enter-a-certain-area-coordinates/210889) and many other, but it doesn't work. I think it's because I use a newer version and the commands are not the same.

I want to teleport every player to `83 15 -177` if he is on the block `171 14 169`

I already tried these commands:

- `/execute @a[x=-71,y=14,z=169] run tp @p 83 15 -177`
  this command won't work because first you have to put after the `/execute` a subcommand
- `/execute at @a[x=-71,y=14,z=169] run tp @p 83 15 -177` here it teleports me all the time

Can someone give the command that it only will tp me if im on the above given coordinates for the version 1.16.5?

Comment: Could you a pressure plate on the block where you want the person to be, then have the pressure plate power the command block with {tp @p 83 15 -177}. It would activate whenever you stand on the pressure plate, or if you don't want to be teleported every time, have the pressure plate and a button run into an and gate that then feeds into the command block?

Answer (score 1):

## Command:

`tp @a[x=171,y=14,z=169,distance=..0.5] 83 15 -177`

## How you can use this:

1. Give yourself a command block.
   `/give @s command_block`
   2. To avoid having your chat being over run by messages, set gamerule CommandBlockOutput to false.
   `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false`
   3. Go to the purple block and stand on top of it. Once you are standing on the block, hold <kbd>shift + f<sub>3</sub></kbd> to find your coordinates. **These will be referred to as x1, y1, and z1**.
   *(Optional) Type your coordinates into chat to help you remember them.*
   4. Now, go to the red block, and repeat step 3. **These will be referred to as x2, y2, and z2**.
   5. Now, go to where you want the command block to be placed, and place it there.
   6. Right-click your mouse on it, and change `Impulse` to `Repeat`.
   7. Now change `Needs Redstone` to `Always Active`.
   8. Now type `tp @a[x=X1,y=Y1,z=Z1,distance=..0.5] X2 Y2 Z2` into the area that says `Console Command`.
   9. Hit `Done`.